# Arquillian tomee remote

Tags: apache-tomee, jboss-arquillian

Using Arquillian 1.1.4.Final and Tomee 1.6.0.2

Took the **tomee-plus-remote** profile setup from the Tomee [information](http://tomee.apache.org/arquillian-available-adapters.html) about arqullian adapters and put it into the Maven pom.xml (with **activeByDefault** true).

Goal is to deploy a MQ JCA rar into the remote Tomee and [configure](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-webspheremq.html) a connection factory to MQ.

Set the arqullian.xml initially to:

```
<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
  <configuration>
    <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
    <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
  </configuration>
</container>
```

Running via JUnit not sure why the webprofile is initialized and started rather than plus (when I have tomee plus specified in Maven):

```
Info: Succeeded in installing singleton service
jun 11, 2014 11:07:52 FM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory init
Info: openejb configuration file is 'C:\Users\MYG\AppData\Local\Temp\arquillian-apache-tomee\apache-tomee-webprofile-1.6.0.2\conf\tomee.xml'
```

Another thing is how to load a tomee.xml configuration.  Thought, the "serverXml" in the **arquillian.xml** (set to src/test/resources/tomee.xml) would work but then everything inside that xml is not recognized as a valid rule.  Can't add directives like **Deployments** as [one does](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/tags/tomee-1.5.2/arquillian/arquillian-tomee-tests/arquillian-tomee-webprofile-tests/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml) with resources.  So how to configure the remote tomee from arquillian?

Comment: Ripped out the profile (tomee-plus-remote) and added classifier to the **arquillian.xml**.  That got the plus zip running rather than the webprofile.  But the problem with loading the tomee.xml is the same.  NullPointerException on "No rules found matching".

Comment: Okej.  serverXml is for the Catalina load of a usual "server.xml".  How do people load via Arquillian a custom tomee.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a conf property to the **arquillian.xml** to for example *src/test/conf* where there is a **tomee.xml** file then it is loaded.  This must be Tomee thing that I didn't know about until now.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, tomee.xml was not really designed for arquillian.xml since all its config can be passed to properties attribute of tomee container using properties format